# LyX won't let me add flags to the converter

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I'm trying to add the "--shell-escape" flag to the pdflatex converter, but LyX won't let me. If I add the flag, save and reopen the preferences window, the change is gone.

And to be honest, I can only "save" the change if I make other change, because LyX will keep the Ok and Apply buttons disabled.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the converter command, you have to click on the "Modify" button. Then click on "OK".

I've been confused by the same thing as you. The dialog UI should be improved.

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows version 2.3.6.1, this option is also "buried" in the settings of the document:

[image]